# Red, yellow and green area while recruiting armies

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

When I use my pre-made army models to recruit, my provinces changing color to green, yellow or red.

It's obvious that green means you have enough ressources to buy your model and red you don't.

But **what does it means precisely when my provinces are yellow** ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, I thought yellow means the province is either already occupied with production, which is not the case or already has the building you are trying to build, which is obviously not the case as you are trying to build troops. How much manpower do you have available? Maybe it means, there isn't enough manpower for all regiments available; but I honestly can't recall ever having seen a yellow colored province during army production.

Comment: I have enough manpower available (30k). I can create a model with 2 armies and an other with 20, both will be yellow. Also, I can only use ONE province to build the model, and they will be enrolled one after one in the same province. It's really strange...

Comment: The number of provinces used to produce the army is defined, when you create the template(model) though. Perhaps it shows yellow, because it would take an extraordinary amount of time to build such a large army in one province.

Comment: I'll try to reduce the number of provinces needed. It could be the problem.

Comment: @Galabyca Did you create a template which recruits troops only from one province?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating an army/navy template, if all provinces are

- **Green** that means that the provinces are all connected and there are enough of them that it will either match or have more provinces than units being queued, and will be able to create them all at the same time.
- **Yellow** means that there are not enough connected provinces to create them all at the same time, and some will double or triple up in unit queue.
- **Red** obviously means that there is a building being produced, or there is another reason that it usually will tell you when you hover over the province.

All of these are applicable to both army, navy, and mercenary recruitment. If you have more questions like these the EU4 wiki usually has all the answers and there are several tutorials on YouTube or other platforms that teach people these tips.